# Polars asof join on next available date

Tags: python, join, python-polars

I have a frame (events) which I want to join into another frame (fr), joining on Date and Symbol. There aren't necessarily any date overlaps. The date in events would match with the first occurrence only on the same or later date in fr, so if the event date is 2010-12-01, it would join on the same date or if not present then the next available date (2010-12-02).

I've tried to do this using search_sorted and join_asof but I'd like to group by the Symbol column and also this isn't a proper join. This somewhat works for a single Symbol only.

```
fr = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        'Symbol': ['A']*5,
        'Date': ['2010-08-29', '2010-09-01', '2010-09-05',
                 '2010-11-30', '2010-12-02'],
    }
).with_columns(pl.col('Date').str.strptime(pl.Date, '%Y-%m-%d')).with_row_index().set_sorted("Date")

events = pl.DataFrame(
    {
         'Symbol': ['A']*3,
         'Earnings_Date': ['2010-06-01', '2010-09-01', '2010-12-01'],
         'Event': [1, 4, 7],
     }
).with_columns(pl.col('Earnings_Date').str.strptime(pl.Date, '%Y-%m-%d')).set_sorted("Earnings_Date")

idx = fr["Date"].search_sorted(events["Earnings_Date"], "left")

fr = fr.with_columns(
    pl.when(
        pl.col("index").is_in(idx)
    )
    .then(True)
    .otherwise(False)
    .alias("Earnings")
)

fr = fr.join_asof(events, by="Symbol", left_on="Date", right_on="Earnings_Date")
fr = fr.with_columns(
    pl.when(
       pl.col("Earnings") == True
    )
    .then(pl.col("Event"))
    .otherwise(False)
    .alias("Event")
)
```

Comment: "If the event date is 2010-08-29 ..." in your example there is no event with 2010-08-29 in the DataFrame `event`, right?

Comment: Absolutely right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are on the right track using [`pl.DataFrame.join_asof`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.join_asof.html). To group by the symbol the `by` parameter can be used.

```py
(
    fr
    .join_asof(
        events,
        left_on="Date", right_on="Earnings_Date",
        by="Symbol",
    )
)
```

```
shape: (5, 5)
┌───────┬────────┬────────────┬───────────────┬───────┐
│ index ┆ Symbol ┆ Date       ┆ Earnings_Date ┆ Event │
│ ---   ┆ ---    ┆ ---        ┆ ---           ┆ ---   │
│ u32   ┆ str    ┆ date       ┆ date          ┆ i64   │
╞═══════╪════════╪════════════╪═══════════════╪═══════╡
│ 0     ┆ A      ┆ 2010-08-29 ┆ 2010-06-01    ┆ 1     │
│ 1     ┆ A      ┆ 2010-09-01 ┆ 2010-09-01    ┆ 4     │
│ 2     ┆ A      ┆ 2010-09-05 ┆ 2010-09-01    ┆ 4     │
│ 3     ┆ A      ┆ 2010-11-30 ┆ 2010-09-01    ┆ 4     │
│ 4     ┆ A      ┆ 2010-12-02 ┆ 2010-12-01    ┆ 7     │
└───────┴────────┴────────────┴───────────────┴───────┘
```

Now, I understand that you'd like each event to be matched *at most once*. I don't believe this is possible with `join_asof` alone. However, we can set all event rows that equal the previous row to `Null`. For this, an [`pl.when().then()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.when.html) construct can be used.

```py
(
    fr
    .join_asof(
        events,
        left_on="Date", right_on="Earnings_Date",
        by="Symbol",
    )
    .with_columns(
        pl.when(
            pl.col("Earnings_Date", "Event").is_first_distinct()
        ).then(
            pl.col("Earnings_Date", "Event")
        ).over("Symbol")
    )
)
```

```
shape: (5, 5)
┌───────┬────────┬────────────┬───────────────┬───────┐
│ index ┆ Symbol ┆ Date       ┆ Earnings_Date ┆ Event │
│ ---   ┆ ---    ┆ ---        ┆ ---           ┆ ---   │
│ u32   ┆ str    ┆ date       ┆ date          ┆ i64   │
╞═══════╪════════╪════════════╪═══════════════╪═══════╡
│ 0     ┆ A      ┆ 2010-08-29 ┆ 2010-06-01    ┆ 1     │
│ 1     ┆ A      ┆ 2010-09-01 ┆ 2010-09-01    ┆ 4     │
│ 2     ┆ A      ┆ 2010-09-05 ┆ null          ┆ null  │
│ 3     ┆ A      ┆ 2010-11-30 ┆ null          ┆ null  │
│ 4     ┆ A      ┆ 2010-12-02 ┆ 2010-12-01    ┆ 7     │
└───────┴────────┴────────────┴───────────────┴───────┘
```

Comment: IIUC, the OP is looking for `strategy='forward'`. E.g., for Date "2010-08-29", s/he wants to match Earnings Date "2010-08-29" if available, else the next available date. With the parameter change, this gets the same result as my solution. Different approach to getting rid of the duplicates.

Comment: @ouroboros1 Actually Hericks is correct. My description of the problem was poor, the TLDR is that Earnings_Date is the stock earnings date, which can fall on any Date, including the weekend. Date is the next trading date. So I'd like to get the next market open date after earnings were released.

Comment: @misantroop Glad it helped! I thought "The date in `events` would match with the first occurrence only on the same or later date in `fr`" was pretty clear (together with your example), but was first confused about the non-existent event date of 2010-08-29.

Answer (score 2):

**Problem**

- Merge `fr` and `events` based on a match between `events['Earnings_Date']` and the exact or *next* date in `fr['Date']` (so: 'looking backward' from `fr`'s point of view), grouped by column 'Symbol'. Keep only the first match.

**Setup**

Let's add 2 symbols (one expecting a match, one expecting zero). Also, it is perhaps easier to use [`pl.Expr.str.to_date`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.str.to_date.html) instead of your [`pl.Expr.str.strptime`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.str.strptime.html).

- `fr`

```py
import polars as pl

fr = (
    pl.DataFrame(
        {
            'Symbol': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
            'Date': ['2010-08-29', '2010-09-01', '2010-11-30', 
                     '2010-09-05', '2010-12-01', '2010-09-01'],
        }
    )
    .with_columns(pl.col('Date').str.to_date('%Y-%m-%d'))
    .set_sorted(('Symbol', 'Date'))
)

fr

shape: (6, 2)
┌────────┬────────────┐
│ Symbol ┆ Date       │
│ ---    ┆ ---        │
│ str    ┆ date       │
╞════════╪════════════╡
│ A      ┆ 2010-08-29 │
│ A      ┆ 2010-09-01 │
│ A      ┆ 2010-11-30 │
│ B      ┆ 2010-09-05 │
│ B      ┆ 2010-12-01 │
│ C      ┆ 2010-09-01 │
└────────┴────────────┘
```

- `events`

```py
events = (
    pl.DataFrame(
        {
            'Symbol': ['A', 'A', 'B'],
            'Earnings_Date': ['2010-06-01', '2010-09-01', '2010-12-01'],
            'Event': [1, 4, 7],
        }
    )
    .with_columns(pl.col('Earnings_Date').str.to_date('%Y-%m-%d'))
    .set_sorted(('Symbol', 'Earnings_Date'))
)

events

shape: (3, 3)
┌────────┬───────────────┬───────┐
│ Symbol ┆ Earnings_Date ┆ Event │
│ ---    ┆ ---           ┆ ---   │
│ str    ┆ date          ┆ i64   │
╞════════╪═══════════════╪═══════╡
│ A      ┆ 2010-06-01    ┆ 1     │
│ A      ┆ 2010-09-01    ┆ 4     │
│ B      ┆ 2010-12-01    ┆ 7     │
└────────┴───────────────┴───────┘
```

**Code**

```py
fr = (
    fr.join_asof(
        events,
        left_on='Date',
        right_on='Earnings_Date',
        by='Symbol'
    )
    .with_columns(
        pl.when(pl.struct('Symbol', 'Earnings_Date').is_first_distinct())
        .then(pl.col('Earnings_Date', 'Event'))
    )
)

fr

shape: (6, 4)
┌────────┬────────────┬───────────────┬───────┐
│ Symbol ┆ Date       ┆ Earnings_Date ┆ Event │
│ ---    ┆ ---        ┆ ---           ┆ ---   │
│ str    ┆ date       ┆ date          ┆ i64   │
╞════════╪════════════╪═══════════════╪═══════╡
│ A      ┆ 2010-08-29 ┆ 2010-06-01    ┆ 1     │
│ A      ┆ 2010-09-01 ┆ 2010-09-01    ┆ 4     │
│ A      ┆ 2010-11-30 ┆ null          ┆ null  │
│ B      ┆ 2010-09-05 ┆ null          ┆ null  │
│ B      ┆ 2010-12-01 ┆ 2010-12-01    ┆ 7     │
│ C      ┆ 2010-09-01 ┆ null          ┆ null  │
└────────┴────────────┴───────────────┴───────┘
```

**Explanation**

- Use [`pl.DataFrame.join_asof`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.join_asof.html) (with default `strategy='backward'`).
- Next, inside [`ppl.with_columns`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.with_columns.html) apply [`pl.when`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.when.html) to set duplicates to `None` (`null`):

  - Use [`pl.struct`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.struct.html) to create a single 'key' for the combination `['Symbol', 'Earnings_Date']` and check [`pl.Expr.is_first_distinct`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.is_first_distinct.html).
  - Where `True` we want to keep the values for `['Earnings_Date', 'Event']`, so we can pass [`pl.col`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/col.html) to `.then`. Where `False`, we will get `None`.

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect default strategy (backward).